# R equivalent to Stata `i' for iterating varnames?

Tags: r, loops, naming

In Stata, you can create a bunch of similarly named variables, differing only in a number (Var1, Var2, ...; Vbl1, Vbl2, ...) by doing:

```
forvalues i = 1/30{
     generate Var`i' = %some way of generating the variable
     generate Vbl`i' = 
}
```

Is there a way of doing this in R?  I have code that generates variables, but I'd like to streamline it.  What I really want is, is there some equivalent to the `i' ?  I.e. some way to define a local macro, iterate over it, and use it in variable names?

This seems like the answer to this question might help ( [R equivalent of Stata's for-loop over macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358675/r-equivalent-of-statas-for-loop-over-macros) ), so apologies if it's redundant.

Comment: The R way to do this [is to use lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) and iteration functions, whether `*apply`, or `replicate` or `for` loops. You can use `assign` and `paste` and `get`, but it's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a data frame called `df`, you could do

```
library(glue)
for(i in 1:30){
  df[[glue("Var{i}")]] <- # some way to generate variable
  df[[glue("Vbl{i}")]] <- # some other generating function
}
```